# Need to change onClick value of a button to another value using select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a little lost at this point in my project. I work for a company that provides translation services. Well, I am making a simple calculator to calculate the cost of a translation based on the number of words in the entire project. It also changes rate based on the amount of words entered. I have that part done. I wrote this and it works:

```
function wordcountprice(){
var price,  final, 
    a=document.getElementById('words'),  
wc= parseFloat(a.value) || 0;
if(wc< 10000) price= .29;
else price= wc<20000? .26: .24; 
final= (wc*price).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('estPrice').innerHTML = 'Your estimated price is: $' + final;}
```

At this point we have 6 types of translation work. Five of them would use that function and the last one would use a basic function with a fixed price. I was thinking I would use a drop down select box to change functions.

I am calling the above function in my HTML like this:

```
  <input type="text" id="words">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="button" value="Calculate" onClick="wordcountprice();"> <br /><b id='estPrice'>Estimated Price</b>
```

I have tried several things and none of them have worked. I assume that the best way to go about this is jQuery's change() or select() function. I have tried making a new function with jQuery like this one:

```
$(function() {
$('#type').change(function() {
    var type = $(this).val();
    $('#button').val(type);
}); });
```

That only changes the value of the button and not the onClick event. I do not know how, or if, it is possible to change the onClick event like that. I don't even know if that is the most efficient method to do what I want to do. I called that function when I was trying it with this HTML:

```
<select id='type'><option value='1'>A</option>
<option value='2'>B</option>
<option value='3'>C</option>
<option value='4'>D</option></select>
```

I am a noob with jQuery and haven't been programming for a while so I am a little rusty.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
$('#button').attr("onClick", "wordcountprice('"+type+"');" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I did not know about jQuery's attribute function. I have tried that in conjunction with what I already have and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple options.

- You could bind a function to the button's click event: `$('#button').click(myFunction)` and either have myFunction check the value of `$('#type')` or keep track of type internally in the javascript when it changes.  Then you can act conditionally within myFunction based on type to get the reaction you want
- You can bind a function to the button for the intial type, then in the change handler, first call `$('#button').unbind('click')`, and then bind a new event (again, `$('#button').click(myNewFunction)` where myNewFunction is chosen based upon type